# Reading Client Side Time Zone in Server Side java class

Tags: java

I have a client side program that sends a time to the server side program. 
I am using Callendar object to pass the time values from client to server.
My client program is located at the Sri Lanka and the server is located at the UK.
When I am sending the time(Ex : 2011-11-21T12:43:41.352+05:30) in client side, as usually the time converting to UK Time at the server (Ex : 2011-11-21T07:13:411.352+00:00). 
What I want to do is I want to get the time that I am sending in the client program with the Time Zone in the client program.(In simple terms, I want to read the time in server without TimeZone conversions applying to the time that is sent by the client side program. So in the server I want to get the time as 2011-11-21T12:43:41.352+05:30 not as 2011-11-21T07:13:411.352+00:00).

Can I know is this possible with java to do and if yes how?

**Client Side :**

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Date indate = new Date(); // this shows as 2011-11-21T12:43:41.352+05:30
searchDateRange_type0.setStart(cal1);
cal1.setTime(inDate);
```

**Serever Side :**

```
SearchDateRange_type0 serachDaterange= criterion_type.getSearchDateRange();
checkInDate     = serachDaterange.getStart().getTime(); //I read this as 2011-11-21T07:13:411.352+00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that when java client Calendar converting Date its setting up its time zone too. if you will to clear this off and only need to get the date from the server Calendar object ,  set the client Calendar time minute and seconds to 0 when you set up the time zone in client.

ex. in client side ,

```
Date indate     = new Date("21-Nov-2011");

Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();     
cal1.setTime(indate);   

// set the time zone same as server time zone.  
cal1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

// then clear out the rest in oder to get only the date.
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

so the server only get the same date passed from the client with out time zone or the hours.

Comment: Thank you very much sameera. +1 for the out of box thinking with the "clearing out the rest in oder to get only the date". But since my program need to pass the time, I re-assigned them instead of clearing them off. (Ex:cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR, indate.getHours());...). Now I get the Time in the server as 2011-11-21T12:43:41.352+00:00 for 2011-11-21T12:43:41.352+05:30. Yes, here I don't get the TimeZone as 05.30 in server side. But it still works for me since it does't convert the Time According to differnt TimeZones. But, Here, it is mondotory to know the Server's TimeZone before hand right?

Comment: yep , you have to know the server time in order to match the both client and server dates.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand that a `Date` value doesn't *have* a time zone. It just represents an instant in time. When you call `Date.toString()`, that uses the default time zone of the system you're calling it on. That's why you're getting the behaviour you are.

So it looks like the instant itself is being read correctly - but if you're interested in the *local* time rather than an *instant* in time, there are two options:

- Pass the time zone identifier (e.g. "Europe/Paris") *as well* as the instant in time
- Pass *just* a local date or date/time and don't try to treat it as an instant in time in the first place

It's hard to know exactly which of those is the most appropriate in your situation. We'd need to know more about what the application is doing, and how you're transferring information.

I *would* recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in date/time libraries though - it's a much better API which will help you distinguish between local times and instants.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon for your comments. Actually what i am developping is an Web service application that provides inventories to the users depending on the date and time that they provides. Here the Date and Time plays a key role.

Comment: @NamalFernando: But are you interested in the *instant* that they provide, or the *local* date and time? What are you doing with the value? For example, there's a big difference between "show me everything matching a certain day *in my local time zone*" and "show me everything before a particular instant in time".

Comment: @ Jon  : I am interesting in the instant they provide. Simply, to provide the inventories, i want the time that they sent as it is - not the time after converting to the server's time zone. Thanks.

Comment: @ Jon  : I am interesting in the instant they provide. Simply, to provide the inventories, i want the time that they sent as it is - not the time after converting to the server's time zone. Thanks.

Comment: @NamalFernando: You're contradicting yourself. 2011-11-21T12:43:41.352+05:30 and 2011-11-21T07:13:411.352+00:00 represent the same instant in time - so the instant *is* being converted appropriately. If you actually only want the instant in time, you're fine. It's if you want the *local* time that you need to change your code.

Comment: @ Jon : No Jon. As you are saying the time that I am getting is correct. That is true. What I wanna do is getting it or convert it to the time of client's time zone. That means I want the Time in the Client's time zone. Thanks

Comment: @NamalFernando: But why? You said you're only interested in the *instant* that they provide. What are you going to compare this with? If it's other instants (e.g. everything stored as UTC in a database) then it shouldn't matter. So that we're talking about the same thing, please read http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_instant.html - it's really important that you understand how an instant in time doesn't depend on time zones - two people in different time zones can agree on the same instant even though they'd see it as different local times.

Comment: @ Jon : I undestand what you are saying Jon. Actually, I am getting inventories from another supplier's syetem-not just using a my own data bese. So, I just have to read the time just as the client enters and it pass to my inventory providers. In this case, If the client enters 13.00+5.30, i must pass 13.00 as it is-in the format of String to my inventory provider. Cauz there's no feature available to specify the TimeZone in their system. They just provide the inventories considering 13.00 in their time zone. Anyway, I 'll go through the links you provided to seek is there any stupidity in me.

Comment: @NamalFernando: Right, so you don't want the instant - you want the local time. I would suggest you use Joda Time's `LocalDateTime` class for this and *never* convert it to an instant (e.g. `java.util.Date`). How do you pass the data to the other supplier's system?

Comment: @ Jon : I pass it using a XML request via POST method. Thanks Jon, as you said I am working on the Joda Time library as well.

Answer (score 1):

After setting time on server, you can call.
Calendar.setTimezone()
Problem is, that you have to know time zone of client.

Comment: Yes exactly. That is my problem too. I want to know a way to get to know the time zone of the client.Thank you very much bugs_ for your comment.

Comment: As Jon said. You have to send TimeZone from client together with Date.

Comment: Yes bugs_, but the problem is that the TimeZone is converting to the Server's time zone.

Comment: You must call getTimeZone on client and send it to server together with Date. And on the server call setTimeZone. Without explicit setting of time zone Server is using its default time zone. (Date contains no information about time zone - It is only instant time. - internally represented as one "long" value.)

Comment: What do you mean by "Without explicit setting of time zone" debug_?. Because , Time zone must be explicitly passed to it like Calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone value). Calender doesn't have "Calendar.setTimeZone()" method (without argument) right?

Answer (score 0):

**Date and Time Conversion to Server time zone format ( Ex : CST to IST )**
**Note** : My server is running in IST format (By default JVM has taken OS Time Zone).

```
    String inputDateString  = "2013-10-26 09:36:00";
    String timezoneID       = "CST";

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    dateFormat.parse(inputDateString+" "+timezoneID);

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(dateFormat.getTimeZone().getID()));

    Date outputDate = formatter.parse(inputDateString);
    System.out.println(outputDate);
```

**Output :**  Sat Oct 26 20:06:00 IST 2013