# Get timezone string from javascript in the format of "Asia/Kolkata"

Tags: javascript, php, timezone, timezone-offset

I wants to find user machine timezone.
But i do not want only offset but i wanted function in javascript that give me timezone string. e.g. "Asia/Kolkata" in these format.

Please help

Thanks
Kalpesh

Comment: see [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520565/how-to-get-client-side-time-zone

Comment: first search for your quries

Comment: see this http://kevalbhatt.github.io/WorldMapGenerato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this site [pageloom](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/downloads) it is helpful

download jstz.min.js and add a function to your html page

```
<script language="javascript">
    function getTimezoneName() {
        timezone = jstz.determine_timezone()
        alert(timezone.name());
    }
</script>
```

and call this function from your display tag